# MakeIndex in Spanish

Tags: indexing, small-caps, roman-numerals, spanish

I've tried to use MakeIndex with the spanish package *babel*. I want to add to the index some words witch are written in the Introduccion, that is numbered with roman numbers in Small Caps. But in this situation MakeIndex rejects these words. I've read that it needs the numbers of the pages to be in lowercase, but it is an error in the Spanish language.

I've tried with *es-preindex* as an option in babel (as you can see [here](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf), page 4) but nothing changes.

Does anybody know how to get the words in the index and the roman numbers in small caps? Thanks in advance.

EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{Bla bla bla }

\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\chapter{Introduction}

Bla blaaaa blaaa blaaa blaa \index{blaa} .....

\mainmatter

\chapter{Blaaaaaaaaaaaa}

Heloooooooo its meeeee \index{meeeee}.

\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'{I}ndice de Materias}

\printindex


\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

The "blaa" isn't shown!

By adding "es-preindex" in the babel package, the result is exactlly the same.

Comment: `makeindex` cannot process complex page numbers (at least not without a lot of tricks)

Comment: Maybe try with `imakeidx` and `xindy`?

Comment: I have read about xindy, but I wondered if there's any "trick". I still don't know why es-preindex doesn't work (it seems an very easy "trick").

Comment: Please, provide a MWE.

Comment: I have just added an example. As you can see the "blaaa" in the introduction is not shown in the index.

Comment: One added `es-preindex` works for me. Are you processing with `makeindex` the `.idx` or the `.eix` file? You must process the latter. If this is the problem I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, according to the message I see when I run makeindex, it processes the .idx . I can read "This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2013] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file hola.idx....done (1 entries accepted, 1 rejected)."

Comment: And does it work if you run `makeindex` on the `.eix` file? (as I explained on my previous comment).

Comment: Sorry - I didn't exactly know how to run makeindex on the .eix file, but have just get it. It works perfectly. Muchísimas gracias @JavierBezos!

Comment: @JavierBezos add an short answer if you want me to mark it as the solution of the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the package option `es-preindex` the `.idx` is pre-processed to generate a new file with extension `.eix`, with the problematic entries fixed. The `.eix` is the file you must process with `makeindex`, not the `.idx`. If you are writing Spanish documents, you may want to have a look at `esindex`, too.

Comment: Please have a look on the follow-up question by the O.P. about the wrong hyperlinks: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318059/makeindex-and-hyperref-in-spanish