# Makeindex and Hyperref in Spanish

Tags: hyperref, indexing, babel, spanish

Following [this answer I was given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317593/makeindex-in-spanish), about how to add small caps roman numbers in the index with babel in Spanish, I have a new problem. With the hyperref package, the links don't go to the right page with these roman numbers. They always go to the very first page of the document.

The link of the table of contents works fine, as well as the words in the index with arabic numbers, but the words in the index with roman numbers don't.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot,es-preindex,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{Example }

\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\chapter{Introduction}

Hello casa \index{casa} .....

\mainmatter

\chapter{Blaaaaaaaaaaaa}

Words \index{m\'{e}dico}.

\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'{I}ndice de Materias}

\printindex


\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

What should I do to correct the links?

EDIT: An warning message is shown:

```
0Warning:\040Replacing\040`OT1/cmr/m/n'\040by\040\\MessageBreak\040faked\040sma
ll\040caps\040on\040input\040line\0403.\012}\\endgroup\040\\uppercase\040{iii}}
} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/
share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share
/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texliv
e/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb>
```

Comment: I'm investigating the `hyperref` internals, which are even trickier than the `spanish`ones ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact two issues. Both can be fixed easily thanks to the hooks provided by the packages.

Firstly, the index entries are modified by `hyperref`, which doesn't recognize a macro defined by `spanish`. This issue is fixed with the following line before `\printindex`:

```
\def\esromanindex#1{\hyperindexformat{\textsc}}
```

Second, there is little bug in `hyperref`, which redefines an internal macro wrongly, because to create the target name it maps *lowercase* small caps to uppercase. But fortunately, there is also a hook, so after loading `hyperref` (and `babel`) write:

```
\makeatletter
\addto\pdfstringdefPreHook{\def\es@roman#1{\romannumeral#1 }}
\makeatother
```

It works for me, which of course doesn't mean it works for everyone ;-). I hope it works also for you, and if so, I'll modify `spanish`for it to work with `hyperref`.

Comment: That's nice! (+1)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot Javier (again!). It's a pleasure to learn LaTeX from the best ones!

Comment: Great! I'll prepare a new version, but not right now (I'm very busy finishing babel 3.10).